# Updating a Bound Property does not update the View in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I am playing around with the MVVM pattern.
I have built a simple application that includes just
-a ListView that displays a simple collection of a UserControl,
-a Button that adds new items to the ListView and
-a ContextMenu that should allow the user to edit the SelectedItem.

---

### The problem:

I have two ICommands bound to my View. `ItemBeginEdit` and `ItemEndEdit`.
They are both called properly throughout the app and the parameters are passed through correctly. Tested.
The CommandParameter for each Command is the Bound source of the ListView.SelectedItem (UserControl).
To make it clear:
-`ListView.ItemSource` = Collection of `Models.Item`
-`ListView.DataTemplate` = `UserControls.Item`
-`UserControls.Item.Source` = `DependencyProperty` of type `Models.Item`.
When changing the whole `Collection`, the `ListView` displays correctly all of my items.
When I am getting a `reference` of `Models.Item` from the `ListView.SelectedItem` and change one of its properties in the ICommand execution, it is not updated on the UI.
I have noticed that if I edit the Collection in the `Constructor` of my `ViewModel`, the UI updates just for that time only.
If I try to changed it back through the `ICommand`, nothing happens.
`INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented to the relevant classes.
I am still learning WPF and XAML. What do I miss?

---

### The code:

-**MainWindow.xaml** (View)

```
<Window x:Class="Demo.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo"
    xmlns:uc="clr-namespace:Demo.Views.UserControls"
    xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:Demo.ViewModels"
    xmlns:b="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Interactivity;assembly=System.Windows.Interactivity"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    x:Name="windowMain"
    Title="Demo"
    Height="300"
    Width="300"
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">

<Window.DataContext>
    <vm:MainVM />
</Window.DataContext>

<StackPanel>
    <Button x:Name="btnAddItem"
            Content="Add"
            Width="150"
            Command="{Binding ItemNew}" />       
    <ListView x:Name="lviewCollection"
              Width="150"
              MinHeight="100"
              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
              ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
              SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
        <b:Interaction.Triggers>
            <b:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
                <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemEndEdit}"
                                       CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
            </b:EventTrigger>
        </b:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <uc:Item DataSource="{Binding}" 
                             IsEditing="{Binding IsEditing}">
                    </uc:Item>

                    <StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference Name=windowMain}, Path=DataContext}">
                            <MenuItem Header="Rename"
                                      Command="{Binding ItemBeginEdit}"
                                      CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedItem}" />
                        </ContextMenu>
                    </StackPanel.ContextMenu>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

---

-**MainVM.cs** (ViewModel)

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace Demo.ViewModels
{
    public class MainVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        //INotifyPropertyChanged
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
        {
            var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName);
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, args);
        }

        //Properties 
        public ObservableCollection<Models.CustomItem> Items { get; set; }

        private Models.CustomItem selectedItem;
        public Models.CustomItem SelectedItem
        {
            get { return selectedItem; }
            set
            {
                if (value == null)
                    return;
                if (value == selectedItem)
                    return;

                selectedItem = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }

        public Commands.CmdItemNew ItemNew { get; set; }
        public Commands.CmdItemBeginEdit ItemBeginEdit { get; set; }
        public Commands.CmdItemEndEdit ItemEndEdit { get; set; }

        //Constructors 
        public MainVM()
        {
            Items = new ObservableCollection<Models.CustomItem>();
            SelectedItem = null;
            ItemNew = new Commands.CmdItemNew(this);
            ItemBeginEdit = new Commands.CmdItemBeginEdit(this);
            ItemEndEdit = new Commands.CmdItemEndEdit(this);

            ReadItems();
        }

        //Methods
        public void SetupItems()
        {
            //Just create demo items. Not used. 
            var items = DatabaseHelper.ReadItems();
            int itemsToCreate = 3 - items.Length;
            while (itemsToCreate > 0)
            {
                CreateItem();
                itemsToCreate--;
            }
        }

        public void CreateItem()
        {
            var item = new Models.CustomItem()
            {
                Name = "New Item"
            };
            DatabaseHelper.Insert(item);
        }

        public void ReadItems()
        {
            var items = DatabaseHelper.ReadItems();
            Items.Clear();
            foreach (var item in items)
                Items.Add(item);
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**CustomItem.cs** (Model)

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using SQLite;

namespace Demo.Models
{
    public class CustomItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        private void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string PropertyName = "")
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                var args = new PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName);
                PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, args);
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties 
        private int id;
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id
        {
            get { return id; }
            set
            {
                if (value != id)
                {
                    id = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private string name;
        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set
            {
                if (value != name)
                {
                    name = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }

        private bool isEditing;
        [Ignore]
        public bool IsEditing
        {
            get
            {
                return isEditing;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value != isEditing)
                {
                    isEditing = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**CmdItemBeginEdit.cs** (ICommand)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Demo.ViewModels.Commands
{
    public class CmdItemBeginEdit : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand implementation 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var item = parameter as Models.CustomItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            item.IsEditing = true;
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties
        public MainVM VM { get; set; }

        //Constructors 
        public CmdItemBeginEdit(MainVM VM)
        {
            this.VM = VM;
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**CmdItemEndEdit.cs** (ICommand)

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Input;

namespace Demo.ViewModels.Commands
{
    public class CmdItemEndEdit : ICommand
    {
        #region ICommand implementation 
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged
        {
            add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }
            remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }
        }
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }
        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            var item = parameter as Models.CustomItem;
            if (item == null)
                return;

            item.IsEditing = false;
        }
        #endregion

        //Properties
        public MainVM VM { get; set; }

        //Constructors 
        public CmdItemEndEdit(MainVM VM)
        {
            this.VM = VM;
        }
    }
}
```

---

-**Item.xaml** (UserControl)

```
<UserControl x:Class="Demo.Views.UserControls.Item"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Demo.Views.UserControls"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         d:DesignHeight="45"
         d:DesignWidth="90">

    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <TextBlock x:Name="tblockName"
                   Text="Name"
                   Margin="2"
                   FontSize="15"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <TextBox x:Name="tboxInput"
                 Text="Name"
                 Visibility="Collapsed"
                 Margin="2"
                 FontSize="14"
                 FontStyle="Italic"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center">
        </TextBox>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

---

-**Item.xaml.cs** (UserControl)

```
using System;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Demo.Views.UserControls
{
    public partial class Item : UserControl
    {
        #region DependencyProperty - DataSource
        public Models.CustomItem DataSource
        {
            get { return (Models.CustomItem)GetValue(DataSourceProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DataSourceProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DataSourceProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DataSource", typeof(Models.CustomItem), typeof(Item), new PropertyMetadata(null, SetDataSource));
        private static void SetDataSource(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as Item;
            var value = e.NewValue as Models.CustomItem;

            if (value == null)
            {
                control.tblockName.Text = string.Empty;
                control.IsEditing = false;
            }
            else
            {
                control.tblockName.Text = value.Name;
                control.IsEditing = value.IsEditing;
            }
        }
        #endregion


        #region DependencyProperty - IsEditing
        public bool IsEditing
        {
            get { return (bool)GetValue(IsEditingProperty); }
            set { SetValue(IsEditingProperty, value); }
        }
        public static readonly DependencyProperty IsEditingProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("IsEditing", typeof(bool), typeof(Item), new PropertyMetadata(false, SetIsEditing));
        private static void SetIsEditing(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var control = d as Item;
            var value = (bool)(e.NewValue);

            if (value)
            {
                control.tblockName.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                control.tboxInput.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                control.tboxInput.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                control.tblockName.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
        #endregion

        //Constructors 
        public Item()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you are assuming that the `DataSource` property of the `Item` control is set whenever a property of the referenced `CustomItem` class changes. That is not the case.

You should remove the `DataSource` property and add properties that are bound to the view model item properties like this:

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <StackPanel>
            <uc:Item Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
            ...
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

The elements in the UserControl's XAML will bind to its properties like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Text,
                  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

---

An alternative to exposing a set of UserControl properties would be that the elements in the UserControl's XAML bind directly to the view model properties, like

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" ... />
```

Then ItemTemplate would then simply contain this:

```
<uc:Item />
```

This would however make the UserControl dependent on the view model type (or more precisely on any type that exposes an equivalent set of properties).

Comment: I missed to include `INotifyPropertyChanged` in my original post. It's there in my code, but the behavior is not what to be expected.  
This Demo app is just a simplified part from a larger project, where the Item is not just a string and a bool. It is consisted of a larger data collection. This demo app just makes the debugging easier. Is there a way to NOT set each property one-by-one to my `UserControl`?

Comment: I created a second DependencyProperty called IsEditing in my UserControl to expose it for Binding. It is bound in my main XAML with the Models.Item.IsEditing. I am setting its value, but I get the same results.

Comment: Please edit your question. We can not guess how exactly your changes look like.

Comment: Please see `MainWindow.xaml` and `Item.xaml.cs`. The former now bounds a second property in the DataTemplate of the ListView and the latter contains that parameter.

Comment: Is it really only that you want to switch the Visibilities of the TextBlock and TextBox according to the IsEditing property? That could easily be done by DataTriggers in the UserControl's XAML.

Comment: I removed the two lines, not the whole `DataSource`. It works now. I don't get why I should remove the whole Property though. In my main application, not this demo one, I have more controls and property that are bound inside the `UserControl`. I simply cannot remove it. 
Regarding your second comment, yeah... First I have to bound the `TextBlock` and `TextBox` value to the same string so they are connected in `TwoWay` mode. Then I have to switch the `Visibility` on `Command` execution so the user may edit the value. At last, I have to update back to a simple database.

Comment: The object that is referenced by the DataSource property is already available by the DataContext property. Since you are creating a direct dependency to the view model, you could as well let the elements in the UserControl's XAML directly bind to view model properties, as explained in the alternative approach in the answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215188/discussion-between-thymiosk-and-clemens).